# Samba shares - Cannot access with users

Tags: ubuntu, users, samba, file-server

I have installed a Samba server on Ubuntu Server 12.04 so I can store files there from my desktop or laptop or whatever.

`/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = xxx
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no

#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[Public]
path = xxx
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0660
directory mode = 0770

[Jochem]
path = xxx
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = jochem
read only = no
create mask = 0660
directory mode = 0770
```

I added a user: `sudo adduser jochem`, `sudo addgroup smbgrp`, `sudo adduser jochem smbgrp`, `sudo smbpasswd -a jochem`

Then restarted the service: `sudo service smbd restart`.

When I open Windows Explorer and go to `\\xxx\` I can see 2 folders: `Public` and `Jochem`. I can access `Public` without any problem, can write files to it, read, etc.
Then when I want to access `Jochem`, I get this window:

[image: credentials window]

I then fill in my username and password as entered via `smbpasswd -a jochem`, but then I get an error message.

What is wrong here? I think it might be because I am logging in via my PC's domain `JOCHEM-PC`, but I've tried `xxx\jochem` and it doesn't work either..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this happened because I was already logged in with a different account to the same network but a different shared directory. I left out other directories since posting the whole config was a bit too much, or so I thought..

It appears, as the error says, you can only be connected to the shared directories with one user at the same time.

Adding my account to multiple shares instead of having different accounts for different shares was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

I [noted for myself](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Samba#Providing_a_network_drive) that I have to set

```
public = yes
```

However I don't have Windows any longer and cannot test if that makes the difference, please tell